# PowerMock - Cannot cast class org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker to interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

Tags: java, testng, mockito, powermock

I am getting an java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when using TestNg + PowerMock + Mockito:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
```

**The root of the problem is:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker to interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
```

My dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |        \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-testng:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.19.0-GA:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-testng-common:jar:1.6.2:test
```

Test class:

```
@PrepareForTest({CrossSiteServletRequestFilter.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.log4j.*"})
@Test
public class CrossSiteServletRequestFilterTest extends PowerMockTestCase{
    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        URL log4jCfg = CrossSiteServletRequestFilterTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log/log4j.xml");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jCfg);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); //<---It crashes here
```

I am completely lost with this error and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` with TestNG.

The [Javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) is saying to use it for JUnit (and I think `MockitoJUnitRunner`/`MockitoRule` is a better way) but not for TestNG.

BTW, `PowerMockTestCase` is the equivalent of `MockitoJUnitRunner` when you use TestNG. 
So, just remove the line and it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem. I have used MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() with TestNG without any problem. Actually, downgrading PowerMock to 1.4.12 the error above doesn't happen.

Comment: And I use PowerMock without `initMocks()` without any problem too ;) So, what appends with 1.6.2 when you remove the line?

Comment: I double check and `initMocks` is useless because `PowerMockTestCase` will inject every `@Mock` in a `@BeforeMethod`.

Comment: You're right, using initMocks() is useless :-) Anyway the error is the same.

Comment: Ok. But as you removed the line, where is located the issue?

Comment: Ups, my bad, you were right!! I had an additional problem related to IBM JDK so I thought it didn't work either. Thanks for taking the time to help me!!

Comment: IBM JDK? sic! If you find any issue with powermock (or mockito), don't hesitate to open an issue on their github repositories ;) Good luck!

Comment: There's an open PR addressing this: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/pull/7. Regards!